# Pinax: Customize Signup and profile

Tags: django, pinax

I want to gather some more information when the user signs up and also display this as part of the profile information - so  that the user can edit it once he creates a login.

How can I extend the sign-up and profile form and model without changing directly pinax code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From pinax [`docs`](http://pinaxproject.com/docs/dev/customization/)

> **Customization**
>
> As more sites are built using Pinax,
>   more best practices will emerge, but
>   for now what we recommend is:
>
> - Always work off a stable release. The most current release is 0.7.1.
> - Use the pinax-admin setup_project command.
> - Make necessary changes to the settings.py and urls.py files in your copied directory.
> - Change the domain and display name of the Site in the admin interface.
> - Develop your custom apps under your new project or anywhere on Python path.
> - Develop your own templates under your new project.

This [`thread`](http://groups.google.com/group/pinax-users/browse_thread/thread/58c9358293fb6105) is very relevant to your question and discusses options for overriding the default pinax apps.

It suggests looking at [`https://github.com/eldarion/idios`](https://github.com/eldarion/idios), (an extensible profile app designed to replace the profiles apps in Pinax).

This [`blog`](http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/python_web.html#sec106) has some comments about overriding the default pinax apps:

Overriding build-in Pinax Applications

> Assuming we want to override
>   $PINAX_ROOT/apps/blog with
>   $PROJECT_ROOT/apps/blog we can do so
>   simply by copying the application and
>   make our project-local (read
>   individual) changes to it. Pinax will
>   then load $PROJECT_ROOT/apps/blog
>   rather than $PINAX_ROOT/apps/blog.
>
> Those who do not care about merging in
>   upstream changes nor submitting
>   bugfixes/features upstream would just
>   issue cp -a $PINAX_ROOT/apps/blog
>   $PROJECT_ROOT/apps and be done. Those
>   who consider themselves good
>   FLOSS-country citizens however care
>   about contributing back as well ...

The default pinax apps you would be looking to override (if necessary), would be:

- http://pinaxproject.com/docs/dev/apps/account/
- http://pinaxproject.com/docs/dev/apps/profiles/

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to have a go at overriding the built-in Pinax applications, which is gone over in a little detail [in this article](http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/python_web.html#sec104). I imagine you'd want to extend (or override) Pinax's Profile model.

[This chap](http://botland.oebfare.com/logger/pinax/2011/03/04/) seems to have been in a situation that sounds like what you want, have a quick read of his chat logs to see what I mean. Sorry that this answer isn't too specific, it's more of a pointer.