# Django Pinax , extending bundled applications

Tags: python, django, pinax

I want to use Pinax for a small project , but I am confused because I don't if can extend/change the behavior and functional of the provided applications . 
Is there any documentation for extending the behavior of the bundled applications ?

example: in registration application ,I want to add custom fields but I am not able to find proper documentation on how to achieve it..( mainly for those which need db changes )

Thanks !

Comment: I answered a similiar question last time. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253132/customized-views-with-django-registration/7253253#7253253

Comment: Here is a good answere about this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950634/pinax-customize-signup-and-profile/5388179#5388179][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950634/pinax-customize-signup-and-profile/5388179#5388179

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can extend the behaviour of the built-in applications. If you are using the pinax basic setup with user accounts and profiles, you will have to add the extra fields you want in apps/profiles/models.py. For a list of field types, see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/

This will create the necessary db fields for you when you run `manage.py syncdb`. If you have already sync'd the db, however, you will have to manually add the db columns. If you don't have any data you care about in that table, you can always just drop the table and it will recreate it. Django doesn't modify db tables once they are created, even if you change the model.

You will also have to modify the signup form to include these new fields and point your urls.py to the new signup form you created. Copy the form from the site-packages/pinax directory to your project. Don't modify them directly.

If you haven't already, you should check out the Django tutorial here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/

This will give you a good idea of how Django apps are put together and how the different pieces interact, so you can do a better job customizing Pinax to your liking. Make sure you know what `models.py`, `urls.py`, `views.py`, and the templates are doing.